# how to move moretab in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

in my applicaton,i have one directions tab in moretab.In directions tab, i displays the safari view through coding like this

```
NSString* url = @"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=33.68325,-117.834073&daddr=33.67425,-117.835073&dirflg=w";//[NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=%@",@"1101+E+Fletcher+Ave+Tampa+FL+33612"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

when click the directions tab it shows the safari browser.But my problem is after open the safari view, iam not able to move the more tab again. now what i want be done is ,when closing this safari view and reopen my application it directly shows the more tab not directions tab.How to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Often times directing the user to Safari can be *very confusing* and some users don't understand how to come back. Consider using UIWebView instead for this since it stays inside your app and also provides you with the control that you are talking about now.

If you absolutely have to direct the user to safari I would take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139588/applicationwillterminate-in-ios-4-0) that talk about how to catch the events of a user leaving your app and different states for that.