# Stop Local Notification when application removed from background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uilocalnotification

I am using Local notification in my application. Now if i remove my application from background then the notification is active. , i want to remove or cancel notifications whenf i remove app from background.

i write code for cancelation in applicationWillTerminate method but this method is not calling .
any other help ?

Comment: seee this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139588/applicationwillterminate-in-ios-4-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cancel all notifications with :

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

or you can cancel a single one like :

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:theNotification];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The method you are searching is either

```
 - (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
```

or

```
 - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

Inside one of those app delegate methods you should call

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

Here's more info: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html