# Tracking the amount of time iOS app is in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate

Is there a way of tracking the amount of time the app is in background and display the same when the app enters foreground in iOS?

Comment: Is "in background" for you different than "terminated"? From your question I'd guess so and that you want to show the time it took for your app to be terminated since it entered background.

Comment: Yeah sort of, What time does it take for an app to be terminated from it enters background state? Any hints as to how to know this?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to know how long the app was in the background before it was terminated? Your comment along with the comment to the answer already given seems to contradict the original question.

Comment: It contradicts based on the fact that it was accepted since it doesn't work for what the OP wants.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple way could be to save the date into NSUserDefaults in your app delegate's `applicationDidEnterBackground:` method, then compare the date from the defaults to the current date in your `applicationWillEnterForeground:` method. Would that work for you?

Comment: No, I need the exact time, If there is a way I am planning to implement some methods based on the time the app is in background

Comment: @user1886224 in what sense would this approach lead to an inexact result?

Comment: `-[NSDate timeIntervalSinceDate:]` would give you a precise time interval in seconds between the two dates, which sounds like what you're asking for. The user defaults value should persist even if the app is terminated.

Comment: Use the time since these two events: application:didEnterBackground: and application:willTerminate: or application:willEnterForeground. Check this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/3139649/1130894) for when the willTerminate is called.